# Operator norm of creation and annihilation operators

Tags: quantum-mechanics, mathematical-physics, operators, hilbert-space, bosons

Are the [creation and the annihilation operators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creation_and_annihilation_operators) $a(f)$ and $a^{\dagger}(f)$ for the bosonic Fock space bounded? What is their norm? So far I did not have found any note about this in the linked Wikipedia article.

Comment: No. Consider the one-particle sector, with states $|n\rangle$ having occupation number $n$. Then $a |n\rangle = \sqrt{n} |n-1\rangle,$ so $\|a |n\rangle \| = \sqrt n.$ This means that $a$ is not bounded.

Comment: @Vibert: Thanks for the quick answer. If you want, you can write an quick answer, so I can accept it.

Comment: @Vibert I second the call for that to be an answer. There's really nothing left to say.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

OK, here you go:

No. Consider the one-particle sector, with states $|n\rangle$ having occupation number $n$. Wlog we can suppose that the states are normalized. Then $$a|n\rangle =\sqrt{n}|n−1\rangle,$$ so $$\|a|n\rangle\| = \sqrt n.$$ This means that $a$ is not bounded. The same goes for $a^\dagger$.